# Libraries that are linked by default

Tags: c, linux, gcc

My code is in test.c:

```
int main(){
return 0;
}
```

The dynamically shared libraries the executable compiled from it depends on are:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ ldd test
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00783000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00935000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ea5000)
```

1. I was wondering what roles the three libraries are playing?
2. Which library does the function `main` belong to? /lib/libc.so.6?
3. Which library does `return` belong to? /lib/libc.so.6?
4. Are the three libraries all that are **dynamically** linked by default by gcc?
5. How can I find out **static** libraries that gcc links to by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `linux-gate.so` isn't really a shared lib, but a part of the kernel that acts like one and makes fast system calls possible. `ld-linux.so` is a piece of code that makes loading other shared libraries possible. `libc.so` is the C library, containing standard functions like `printf` and `strcpy`.
2. `main` doesn't belong to any library. It belongs to your program, in the sense that its assembled version is stored entirely in the `test` binary file.
3. `return` is not a function but a C language construct.
4. No, it also links in `libgcc`, which is apparently not a shared library on your system (or it would show up) and some startup code. `g++` would additionally link in `libstdc++.so` (the C++ standard library) and `libm.so` (the math part of the C standard library).

Comment: Thanks! Are the three libraries all that are linked by default by gcc?

Comment: @Tim: added that to the answer.

Comment: (1) Are the three libraries all that are **dynamically** linked by default by gcc? (2) How can I find out static libraries that gcc links to by default?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) I'm not sure, but you can get rid of them with `gcc -nodefaultlibs`. See also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html, `ld(1)` and the `-Xlinker` option to `gcc`.

Comment: `linux-gate` does not "make system calls possible". In fact it's largely useless for that. It can make them slightly faster (or a lot faster on a very few specifically broken 32-bit Intel CPU models) but it can't be used for all syscalls. The main thing it's good for is that it has **very** fast routines for getting the current system time without entering kernelspace, but sadly they're only available on x86_64 at this time. And they don't work like syscalls but like library calls.

Comment: @R..: How differently do  syscalls and library calls work? I feel syscalls work just like library calls.

Comment: Syscalls generally work by loading the syscall number and arguments into registers and performing a special asm instruction to enter kernelspace. This is very different from library calls which would use whatever the platform's normal function calling convention is, usually involving a call instruction or pushing the return address onto the stack and jumping to another virtual address in userspace.

Comment: Of course, `fork`, `execlp`, `write` and friend are actually library functions wrapping the actual system call instruction, setting up arguments, etc. System calls are made to look like library calls by `libc`. @R..: thanks for the correction wrt. `linux-gate.so`.

Comment: The system call refers to the actual operation of passing to kernelspace to request the kernel do something. All of those functions you mentioned are actually much more than just wrappers for system calls. `fork` is required to run `pthread_atfork` handlers, `execlp` assembles an argument list and does a path search before calling `execve`, and `write` is a cancellation point which means it needs logic for cancellation.

Comment: But the term "system call" is also loosely applied to these wrappers, no matter how heavy-weight they are, e.g. by `intro(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `linux-gate` is a virtual shared object that acts as a connection to system calls within the kernel. `libc` is glibc, which provides functions such as `printf()` and so on. `ld-linux` is the glibc loader, which allows loading of other shared objects.
2. `main()` belongs to your code. It is called by `crt1.o` which is linked into the executable by gcc (well, ld specifically).
3. `return` is not a function but rather a language construct, so gcc turns it directly into code contained within the object (and eventually executable) file. As an aside, the value returned from `main()` is caught by `crt1.o` and turned into a program result code.

Comment: Thanks! Are the three libraries all that are linked by default by gcc?

Comment: Is crt1.o a library? If yes, a dynamically shared library or a static library?

Comment: In C mode, those are the libraries that are dynamically linked. Other languages can add other libraries (e.g. `libstdc++`).

Comment: `crt1.o` is an object file. It is statically linked into the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Exelent description about [how does linux execute my main()?](http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html) There you will find the answer and probably a lot more!

Answer (score 1):

`linux-gate` is a virtual library that provides access to system functions. Its full name is the Linux Virtual Dynamic Shared Object. It's used by `libc`.

`libc` is the C run time. It's what actually calls main() for you. (It's possible to bypass this if you don't use any C functions.)

`ld-linux` is the dynamic linker, which actually knows how to load and call the C run time for you.

`main` lives in test.o, not in a library.

`return` is a keyword, not a function. It directs the compiler to emit code to cause the function to return control to its caller.

Answer (score 1):

`ld-linux.so` provides the magic that helps `ldd` work.
`libc.so` is part of the C runtime library.  Among other things, the runtime library contains the actual entry point that calls `main`.

`main` is provided by your code.
`return` is not a function, it's a keyword in the C language.